# Prove the following inequality: $a^2+c^2-b^2>\frac{a^2c^2}{b^2}$

Tags: inequality, buffalo-way

Suppose we the following real numbers:

{$a$,$b$,$c$} $\in \mathbb{R}^+$, where $a>b>c$. Is there any way to prove the following:

$a^2+c^2-b^2>\frac{a^2c^2}{b^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=1,\;c=-1$.

Then as $b \to 0^{+}$, the LHS approaches $2$, while the RHS approaches $+\infty$.

Edit:

My answer above was based on the original question, with $a,b,c$ unrestricted in sign.

If we assume $a > b > c > 0$, we can argue as follows . . .

Let $x = a/b,\; y = c/b$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&a^2+c^2-b^2>\frac{a^2c^2}{b^2}\\[4pt]
\iff\;&\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{b^2}>\frac{a^2c^2}{b^4}\\[4pt]
\iff\;&x^2 + y^2 - 1>x^2y^2\\[6pt]
\iff\;&x^2y^2-x^2-y^2 + 1 < 0\\[6pt]
\iff\;&(x^2-1)(y^2-1) < 0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which is true since $x > 1$ and  $0 < y < 1$.

Comment: Sorry, It is my mistake, I will update the question by replacing $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: @Ahmed: My latest edit addresses your new conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This inequality is equivalent to
$$a^2b^2+b^2c^2-b^4-a^2c^2>0.$$
Can you prove or refute this?

Answer (score 1):

Let $b=c+u$ and $a=c+u+v$, where $u$ and $v$ are positives.

Hence, $$b^2(a^2+c^2-b^2)-a^2c^2=4uvc^2+2uv(3u+v)c+u^2v(2u+v)>0.$$

PS. Now I see that
$$b^2(a^2+c^2-b^2)-a^2c^2=-b^4+a^2b^2+c^2b^2-a^2c^2=(a^2-b^2)(b^2-c^2)>0.$$

Answer (score 0):

The special case.  Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be the sides of a triangle such that angle $(bc)=90^o$. Then,

$$a^2 + c^2 - b^2 - 2ac \cos(ac) > \frac{a^2c^2}{b^2} - 2ac\cos(ac),$$
$$0 > \frac{a^2c^2}{b^2} - 2ac\frac{c}{a} = \frac{a^2c^2}{b^2} - 2c^2.$$

As $b \to a$, the RHS of the inequality is $c^2 - 2 c^2 <0$. As $b \to c$, the RHS of the inequality is $a^2 - 2c^2 =0$ (this is because $\cos(45^o) = 1/{\sqrt2}$).  Due to the continuity of the RHS w.r.t $b$, the RHS must be strictly negative for values of $a>b>c$.

May be you can generalize it from here.

Comment: How is $a^2 + c^2 - b^2  < 0$ possible if $0 < b < a$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. You are right. I confused $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Corrected

Comment: @Beck: You replaced $2ac\,\cos(ac),$ by $c^2$, but that's not correct. It should be $2c^2$. Then you don't get a contradiction.

Comment: @quasi My original comment was to the unedited answer, which has since been changed.

Comment: @UmbertoP: I accidentally at-signed you, when I meant to ping Beck. My point (intended for Beck) is that Beck's edited answer is wrong.

Comment: @UmbertoP.Sorry for this. Corrected

Comment: @Beck: No, your answer is still not correct. For fixed $a,c$, as $b$ approaches $c$, the RHS approaches $a^2 - 2c^2$ which is close to zero, but not equal to 0. It's still negative. The angle approaches $45$ degrees, but since $b > c$, the angle is always greater than $45$ degrees. So there's no contradiction.

Comment: @quasi. My answer does not say that there is a contradiction

Comment: @Beck: Ok, I see -- you proved it for the special case where $a>b>c>0$ and $a,b,c$ are side lengths of a right triangle. Seems OK.